# Accessing system's terminal from bootable usb kubuntu

Tags: command-line, nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, 20.10

Hello I am new at ubuntu. By mistake I removed a package named something like x11 nouveau which made me unable to access GUI so I wanted to boot from my bootable usb drive so that I could be able to access the system's main terminal to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that it may be easier if you can get to the command line from a normal boot just to add the package since you know what is missing.  Just boot and run:

```
sudo apt install <package name>
```

If you get to the login screen and cannot get to a GUI just use CTRL+ALT+F1 to get a tty and you should be able to run your commands there.

Comment: But the problem is that I have no internet connection on ethernet and I don't know how to connect to wifi in terminal

Comment: And my system does not have ifconfig

Comment: Networking should already be running by the time it goes to launch the window manager.  Did you ever have networking running?  Btw, Ubuntu does not install ifconfig by default instead use the ip command. For instance, to list all of your network devices: ip a